# Magento 2 - Error: Attribute with attributeCode “X” does not exist

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I have created a new attribute for a product and added that to the default attribute set. When I then click to navigate to Products > Catelog so that I can implement the attribute, I get the following error:

Attribute with attributeCode "X" does not exist.

Any suggestions on how to resolve that?

I have been following this tutorial: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-2-x-create-manage-product-attributes.html

And this error occurs in step 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the below commonds using ssh.

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by clearing out the contents of var/generation.
The issue comes from the attribute factory. Until it's rebuilt it doesn't know your attribute exists